# ¿Cómo imprimir método con la clase File?

Tags: java, filesystem, metodología

Banda como imprimo en el main el archivo, lo encontré en un video de youtube, pero no encuentro la forma de abrir el archivo y que lo muestre en la consola:

```
    public void leerArchivo() throws FileNotFoundException{
    File f=new File("/Users/Krjkn/Documents/Prueba/test.txt");
    FileReader a= new FileReader(f);
    
}
public void leerArchivo2()throws IOException{     
   leerArchivo();
   
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    
}}
```

Comment: Revisa el artículo sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), edita tu pregunta y ponle formato de código. Además, recuerda que debes aportar un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), (Tu pregunta debe de poder reproducirse)

Answer (score 1):

Yo leo los archivos de texto con un Scanner y un while, aclaro... no se si esta es la manera correcta en la que se realiza, pero es la que me funciona a mi, he visto varias maneras de leer un archivo de texto, pero la mas simple creo que es esta:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine())
}

scanner.close();
```

Te aconsejo que antes de leer los archivos compruebes si el archivo es legible o no, una manera simple seria comprobar la extensión del archivo:

```
private boolean isValid(final String nameFile) {
    if(nameFile.endsWith(".txt")) { // extensión compatible
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Y bueno también algo fundamental es que comprobar si el archivo existe realmente:

```
file.exists();
```

Con esto dicho el código de como leo los archivos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

public Main() {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    
    File file = new File("file.txt");

    try {
        // ¿Se puede leer?
        if(file.exists() && isValid(file.getName())) {
            // See
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            
            scanner.close();
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       // si scanner != null cerrar
    }
}

/**
 * Comprueba si la extensión del archivo es compatible.
 * 
 * @param nameFile
 * @return
 */
private boolean isValid(final String nameFile) {
    if(nameFile.endsWith(".txt")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Aunque es totalmente válido leer con Scanner, solo es recomendado para leer texto con formato

Comment: Una de las mejores maneras son a través de BufferedStreams, Si quieres echarlo un ojo, Oracle ofrece [su tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) sobre los Input/Output Streams